# When is SELECT necessary in PL/pgSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-10

While assigning the result of a function or expression to a variable in PL/pgSQL, when is it necessary to use a `SELECT` statement (sub-query)?

This may be just my misconception from SQL. I thought that everything should be enclosed in a `(SELECT ...)` (even if it just involves computing a number), e.g.

```
$$
DECLARE parts text[];
BEGIN
  parts := (SELECT string_to_array(my_str,'_') );
...
$$
```

but I just found that it works without the `SELECT`:

```
parts := string_to_array(my_str,'_');
```

(It's almost as if I can use PL/pgSQL as if its Pascal.)

*In general, what kind of expressions can be used directly without `SELECT` in computing values*?

Comment: Any _expression_ can be used without a SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an educated guess.

It seems that the `SELECT` is unnecessary because it's already present, e.g. in the implicit `SELECT ... INTO` that an assignment `:=` is equivalent to. From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT):

> An assignment of a value to a PL/pgSQL variable is written as:
>
> variable { := | = } expression;
>
> As explained previously, the expression in such a statement is
>   evaluated **by means of an SQL SELECT command** sent to the main database
>   engine.

An example may be shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328820/683218), where:

```
name := (SELECT t.name from test_table t where t.id = x);
```

can also be written as

```
name := t.name from test_table t where t.id = x;
```

This seems possible because the second simplified form is equivalent to a `SELECT INTO` in PL/pgSQL:

```
SELECT test_table.name INTO name FROM test_table WHERE id = x;
```

The first form would be equivalent to:

```
SELECT (SELECT t.name from test_table t where t.id = x) INTO name;
```

, which has a redundant layer of `SELECT` that can be removed.

On the other hand, when an implicit `SELECT` is not present, an explicit `SELECT` seems necessary. For example, the same function **cannot** be used directly (i.e. without `SELECT`)

```
string_to_array(my_str,'_');
```

if it's not in an assignment to a variable.

Comment: `some_var := string_to_array(my_str,'_');` will absolutely work (assuming `some_var` is defined as an array)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, my point is that it works only because there is an `SELECT` implicit  in `:=`. So there is still a `SELECT` involved in a sense. If `string_to_array` were a void function, then calling it directly without the assignment part won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer every expression is a select statement.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-expressions.html

> All expressions used in PL/pgSQL statements are processed using the server's main SQL executor.

That means you can have from clauses and the like in assignments and after if statements.

```
IF count(*) > 10  FROM foo_table GROUP BY ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1 
THEN
   -- handle the case when there exists a y group larger than 10
```